# Speeding up autowrap from Sympy

Tags: python, performance, sympy

I'm trying to convert a large number of Sympy expressions using the `autowrap` function. It is however a slow process.
I've tried parallelizing with some Python packages, but I keep getting errors.
My question is, is it possible to speed up the autowrapping process? Like with parallelization or something?

If it is necessary, I can post parts of my script to show how my particular case can be solved, but I'd like to try something more general.

**EDIT:** The way my code works is (probably not the best way) it creates some expressions from a general expression and its derivatives (Euler-Lagrange equations for those interested). Said expressions are then stored in an array (list of lists) from where they are being called to be autowrapped. Once that is done, they are saved in another array.

This I can do with a simple for loop. It is very very slow for when I have, let's say 400 (aka 20^2) of those expressions.

I've tried using `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` because I'm already using it in another part of my code. But that throws a `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` error, unless I try to wrap only one function. Then it works fine.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` does the same thing (or it complains about a `wrapper_module_#` missing which sometimes is on the tempdir I indicated).

From `multiprocessing.Pool` I only get `Exception in thread Thread-#:` and then it keeps running forever unless I stop it.  Then it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrapper_module_#'`.

So I'm not sure why those modules are missing when they are really not.

I'll try to shorten my code as much as possible and I'll post it in a few hours.

**EDIT 2:** So here's a piece of code that throws the same or similar errors.

```
# This is the setup (declaring equations and such)
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
import itertools
import os # <- To change directories because it appears that it changes automatically when using Process and ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor,ThreadPoolExecutor

cwd = os.getcwd()
x,y,dx,dy = sp.var('x y dx dy')

eq = list()
eq.append(sp.cos(x)*dx + y*dy) # <- Some random equations
eq.append(3*x*dx + dy)         #    equations as examples.

coeff1 = [eq[0].coeff(dx),eq[0].coeff(dy)] # <- Coefficients of eq[0]
coeff2 = [eq[1].coeff(dx),eq[1].coeff(dy)] # <- Coefficients of eq[1]
coeff = [coeff1,coeff2] # <- This is my list of lists of coefficients
                        #    (currently Sympy expressions)
arguments = [x,y] # <- Arguments for my equations.
```

Here comes the fun part:

- Using list comprehension to call `autowrap` for every entry of my `coeff` array works just fine.

```
coeffComp = [[autowrap( coeff[i][j] , backend='cython', tempdir=cwd+'/CoefficientsComprehension',args=arguments) for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)]

# To visualize:
print(coeff)
# returns [[cos(x), y], [3*x, 1]]

# If I evaluate in (x=1,y=0)
print([[coeffComp[i][j](1,0) for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)])
# returns [[0.5403023058681398, 0.0], [3.0, 1]], which is correct.
```

- However, trying to work with `ProcessPoolExecutor` or `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
def AutoWrapCoefficients(Index): # <- Function to map
    i,j = Index
    return autowrap( coeff[i][j] , backend='cython', tempdir='./CoefficientsPoolExecutor',args=arguments)


def ToPyOfArray(): # <- Mapping function
    TempArr = list()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(AutoWrapCoefficients, itertools.product(range(2),repeat=2))
        for res in results:
            os.chdir(cwd)
            TempArr.append(res)
    return TempArr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    coeffFunctions = ToPyOfArray() # <- Throws described errors
```

- And with `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map( AutoWrapCoefficients, itertools.product(range(2),repeat=2)) # <- Throws described errors
```

Comment: I suggest to add some simple example to reproduce and speed-up, maybe also your tries of parallelization.

Comment: I get some speedup applying autowrap to a sympy matrix, e.g. `callable = autowrap(sp.Matrix(coeff)); callable(1,0) # returns the desired matrix`. Executing callable also becomes much faster without list comprehension.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yeah, that I think could be an answer in this case. It leaves the question open for a more general case, though. Or what if I wanted to speed up even more this process, because I can see that it still uses only one core (but it already is **very** fast compared to my previous attempt).

Comment: @LuisSibaja I think that your problem is somewhat unusual since the bottleneck is in the call to autowrap, as opposed to applying the compiled function. I imagine that `autowrap` was build with "compile once, run many times" idea in mind. As an aside, you may want to check out [Julia](https://julialang.org/).